# How to turn on Sublimelinter in Sublime Text 2 (on a mac)

Tags: javascript, installation, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I've been trying for some time to get SublimeLinter to start, but don't really see it do anything.

I downloaded it here: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter
Installed with Sublime Package Control http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control
It added SublimeLinter under Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings
It shows me the README.md and it gives me a Package Control message where it says that SublimeLinter by default runs in the background.

But when I try typing in some syntax errors it doesn't say a word or hint that something is wrong. Nor when I save.

What's up? Where is the on-switch that I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on Linux when installing from package manager (old version). The solution was to download the last version from Github and manually copy it in packages folder.

You'll see that the size of the folder containing indexes for the language scanned (PHP in my case) is incrementing.